# In Java, what's the best way to get numbers from a one-line String?

Tags: java, string, formatting

For example:

input:
14 5 1

What's the best way to get these three values into three int variables?

Also, does it make any difference if we were dealing with double values?

Comment: my hand is itchy to answer, but what you've tried so far?

Comment: The "best way" is a matter of opinion.  If you are just wanting us to write code for you, that is off topic.

Comment: I've been using a for structure having a ' ' character as separator. But now I have just learned that if you simply Scanner's nextInt() three time, it'll get the job done. Is there an even simpler way than that?

Comment: @Djaildo Quaresma atleast mark the answer that suited you for this question.

Comment: Wanting you to write code for me? How did you get there? I'm just asking because I've been using a for structure, and it always takes a while to have everything done. Please don't put words in my mouth. All I want is what I asked: the best/simplest way to do that.

Comment: @DjaildoQuaresma Im gonna assume that too, and I believe everyone does, without you posting your current code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Scanner` class.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("14 5 1");
System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
```

This snippet would output

```
14
5
1
```

You can use `nextDouble()` instead of `nextInt()` when working with `double`s

If you don't know how many numbers you are going to have you can use a while loop to keep reading numbers. You could rewrite the above as

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("14 5 1");
while(scan.hasNextInt())
    System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
```

The output should remain the same. Use it if it's any simpler for your program.

Comment: Don't mention it. You can always look up the Scanner documentation (here: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)) if you want to see what else you can do with a Scanner

Answer (score 4):

Using Java 8 you can get the whole string into a stream of numbers like so:

```
IntStream intStream = Arrays.stream(input.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt);
```

From there, you can convert the `Stream` to an array:

```
intStream.toArray();
```

You can act on it directly:

```
intStream.forEach(n -> {
   // do something here with n
});
```

...and much more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

**Edit:**  As Chris pointed out, `IntStream` has a few more utilities tailored specifically to Integers: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html

Have fun!

Comment: `Integer::parseInt` is more concise than `str -> Integer.parseInt(str)`, and I would also choose `mapToInt` instead of `map`, since `IntStream` has more capabilities than `Stream<Integer>`.

Comment: Seeing your answer made me realize that I need to take a look at Stream :). It's very elegant!

Comment: @cyc115 If you're dealing with streams of numbers, also look at `IntStream`, `LongStream`, and `DoubleStream`; they're even more awesome. :-D

Answer (score 2):

you can get those numbers in one line, assume you already did it and stored on a `String s;`
you can split them into a String Array by doing `String [] k = String s.split(" ");` , this will split the `String s` onto 3 different Strings in one String array separated by space, after you do that, convert them to use wherever you want like these,

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(k[0]);
double b = Integer.parseDouble(k[1]);
double c = Integer.parseDouble(k[2]);
```

Comment: `k[0]`, not `k.[0]`. Similarly for the other lines.